# How to change value in a QTP data table?

Tags: vbscript, datatable, qtp

Could anyone help me figure out how to enter a value into a QTP data table using VBScript? I'm trying the following line, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
datatable.Value(D,"sheetName")="A"
```

What is wrong? I am used to other languages and just cannot see any problem here.

Comment: FYI, QTP uses VBScript, not VBA.

Answer (score 2):

What is the `D` you're using? Is it a variable holding the column name? If not and you mean to use the `D` column then you have to quote it so that QTP (VBScript actually) knows you mean the string `"D"`.

```
datatable.Value("D","sheetName")="A"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know zilch about QTP tool.  However, your syntax looks correct based on [this example. (see heading *Adding Value to you a local sheet*](http://qtp.blogspot.com/2009/03/qtp-writing-to-datatable.html)

Based on the information given, I would take a stab that you may have not referenced the QTP DLL, you have ON ERROR RESUME NEXT in your code *AND* you do not have OPTION EXPLICIT set at the top of your module.

Start by making sure you have the correct DLL referenced and adding this line to the top of the code:

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
```

If you've done that, then add more information that could help one deduce the problem (e.g. full code sample).

Answer (score 0):

The way that you get data from datatable in QTP is, first import the Excel sheet into your datatable (Either Global or Local), then try to get data from datatable using following Syntax

Datatable(columnName,dtGlobalSheet) if imported in Global sheet

Datatable(columnName,dtLocalSheet) if imported in Local sheet

Importing Data

---

myFile = "C:\datasheet\excelone.xls"

datatable.Importsheet myFile,1,Global

Enter Value

---

DataTable("Coumn1Data", dtGlobalSheet)

This way you can get data from Excel sheet.

Thanks,

Karthik